# Efficient data structure for multidimensional searching on intervals and keys

Tags: data-structures, search-trees, balanced-search-trees, searching, intervals

I am searching for a data structure that can capture a database, which is consisted of one column of **intervals** (like `[0, 2], [4, 6]`) and one/two columns of **keys** (like `{'a', 'c'}`).
I want to be able to do efficient indexing in both ways such as queries like the following are computationally balanced:

- "give me the keys that appear in the interval frame of 1 and 5" or
- "give me the intervals where 'a' exists"

“Computationally balanced” means that there is no 'hierarchy' e.g. from sorting and secondly to be as much redundant as possible.

Also I want to be able to efficiently union/intersect two databases based on intervals (and keys of course).

Here are some notes from approaches I've tried but do not seem to do the trick:

1. Interval-Set/Interval-Map (Boost): Information is not at all redundant:
   `(1, 5)->'A'` and `(4, 8)-> 'B'`, will be stored as
   `(1, 4)->{'A'}, (4,5)->{'A', 'B'} and (5, 8)->{'B'}`.
   It is also hierarchical.
2. R-trees (Boost): Everything is geometrical.
   On the contrary key '1' is **not** closer to key '2' than key '3'.
   Complicated search queries do not appear feasible.
   Things are distinguished between keys and value.

Comment: "Approaches ... do not seem to do the trick". Can you explain how or why they do not do the trick?